# Spring + Hibernate Validator: Change Default Messages (not working)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

So I want to get custom default messages working, like it has been asked (and solved) here several times, but I still can not get it to work.

My Code so far:

Application,java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
        SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("WEB-INF/messages/messages");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return source;
}

@Bean(name = "validator")
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validatorFactoryBean;
}



}
```

Now

```
messageSource.getMessage(result.getFieldError("projectName"), null)
```

will work just fine and I get my custom error message.

But

```
result.getFieldError("projectName").getDefaultMessage()
```

does still output the standard default messages.

How can I make it work? :)

Comment: If I remember correctly the Validator getMessage used a prefix. Easiest way to find out which messages the validator tries to get is a breakpoint.

Comment: Sry, but I don't understand, what you mean. Can you explain further, please?

Comment: result.getFieldError("projectName") : returns the very first error  associated with the given field. I believe same is happening in your case.

Comment: I don't see how this affects the error message...

Comment: To check which message key is used debug your application by setting a breakpoint here : `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate()` (line 362 in v5.0.2)